# What is the meaning of hadith Sahih al-Bukhari 105?

Tags: hadith-interpretation

Is he saw talking about some certain day of month? And does sacred of chastity, blood and property of another means we should be honourable with these of others?

Comment: Numbers are not a reliable way to reference hadiths as different publications may number them differently. It would help if you quote the hadith you're having issue with.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

**Asalaam alaikum**

I believe this is the narration which you are referring to,

> **“Allah has made sacred upon you the blood, wealth and honour of each other, just as the sacredness of this day of yours in this land of yours in this month of yours. “** (Bukhari)

There are other similar narrations of this message as we find,

> “The blood, wealth and honour of the Muslim are sacred to all Muslims” (Muslim)

And again,

> Abdullah ibn Umar (ra) narrated that he saw the Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) making tawaf of the Ka’bah and saying, “How delightful you are, and how great is your scent! How magnificent you are, and how great is your sanctity! But by the one in whose hand is the soul of Muhammad, the sanctity of a believer, his wealth and his blood, is greater in the sight of Allah than your sanctity, and we do not think of him except good.” (Ibn Majah)

**THE EMPHASIS** on the sanctity of a Muslim is laid out in these ahadith. This narration in bukhari is during the last hajj of our beloved prophet ﷺ and it was said on the day of *arafah* in the month of *dhul hijjah* and on the *land of Makkah*. Just imagine the superiority of these compared to others, thus to bring out the importance it's narrated as such.

**FOR MORE** clarity as we look into the commentries of this Hadith, we can understand better.

> Imam Ibn Hajr al-Asqalani notes in Fath al-Bari (one of the most authoritative commentaries on Sahih Bukhari) that the intent of ‘blood, wealth, and honour’ is the spilling blood, wrongful acquisition of wealth and defamation of honour. He also explains that the mention of the sacredness of the land, month and day is mentioned and compared to because the sacredness of these things was established in the minds of the Arabs even before Islam, as opposed to the sanctity of blood, wealth and honour which was an accepted target in Jahiliyyah. Thus the Shari’ah emphasised to them that the sanctity of Muslim blood, wealth and honour is even greater than the sanctity of the land, month and day.

The emphasis of these ahadith is also communicated in the Quran as Allah azzawajjal said,

**“And whosoever kills a believer intentionally, his recompense is Hell, to abide therein forever, and the Wrath of Allah is upon him, and His curse; prepared for him is a grievous torment” (al-Nisaa’: 93).**

**REGARDING** the last part of your question if we should be honourable of these rights of others,

> *Rasulallah (ﷺ) swore by Allah (سبحانه و تعالى) that the sanctity of the Muslims, their wealth and their blood is greater than that of the Ka’bah. The seriousness of this matter is evident in that fact alone.*

May Allah the mighty and sublime grant us mercy and guide us to the straight path.

**Allah knows best**

Comment: May Allah swt bless you so much in this world and in the hereafter. Thank you so much for answering this and especially with the details, JazakAllahal khair and I'll pray InshaAllah Allah swt reward you for it .Ameen